# Complex number alternative notation

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

I have seen the following notation for a complex number in a book on digital signal processing:

$$c = M\angle \phi$$

Did anyone see such notation before and how to interpret it?

Comment: It probably means $c = Me^{i \phi} = M(\cos \phi + i\sin \phi).$ That is, $M$ is the [modulus](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html) of $c$ and $\phi$ is the [argument\phase angle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html) of $c.$

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen it before, but my guess is that $M\angle\phi$ means $M\bigl(\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi)\bigr)$.

Comment: @Michael Munta: I suspect I've seen it before, and a check with [**Mathematics for Science and Engineering**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.133657/page/n73/mode/2up) by Philip L. Alger (a book I've had since around 1975 while in high school---which incidentally I cited [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1990/745), and I'm pretty sure I would have read the part it appears in) shows that this notation appears on p. 66, line $-7$: $\;[\cdots]$ *or simply as* $r \angle \theta,$ *which is read as* "$r$ *at the angle* $\theta$"

Answer (score 1):

You can notice there is the angle sign ($\angle$) before $\phi$, so the autor intends to use angles. In particular this type of notatoon is the same as:
$$c=Me^{i\phi }=M(\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi))$$
Or, in other words the complex number of mudulus $M$ and $arg(c)=\phi$